# Why does ForkJoinPool::shutdownNow return an empty list?

Tags: java, java-8, executorservice

ExecutorService has a method

```
List<Runnable> shutdownNow()
```

which

> returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.

However, ForkJoinPool always returns a Collection.emptyList(). Since, ForkJoinPool's implementation

> attempts to cancel and/orstop all tasks, and reject all subsequently submitted tasks,

shouldn't it also return the list of tasks that were cancelled?

Comment: You quoted yourself *returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.* a cancelled task doesn't await execution

Comment: @Lino Then I'm not sure why ThreadPoolExecutor would return a list of tasks. It also _attempts to stop all actiivel executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a listo f the tasks that were awaiting execution._ to quote the javadoc.
Is there a difference between the way shutdownNow() works for the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why an empty list ?
The doc explains that (emphasis is mine) :

> This method cancels both existing and unexecuted tasks, **in order to
>   permit termination in the presence of task dependencies**. So the method
>   always returns an empty list (unlike the case for some other
>   Executors).

Why ?

Because a `ForkJoinPool` is a "special" implementation of `ExecutorService`.
It may have some task dependencies related to performed forks.
For example, in the below example if the submitted task is stopped, you also want that the subtask 1 and the subtask 2 to be also terminated :

[image: simple example of fork join]
That's why when you stop tasks for a `ForkJoinPool` instance you will return a `List` that indicates that no more tasks are waited. In this way, any tasks waiting for some other tasks termination or currently processed are also terminated as not required any longer.
While I am not sure that the return of the method (I have not found clues about it) be used for the current implementation.